# Maven how does test classes access source classes

Tags: java, maven

I have a typical maven project where the directory structure is:

```
src/main/java/SrcClass.java

public class SrcClass {
    public int srcMethod() {return 0;}
}

src/test/java/TestClass.java

@RunWith(JunitParamsRunner.class)
public class TestClass
@Test
public void testThis() {
     SrcClass srcClass = new SrcClass();
     int result = srcClass.srcMethod();
     assertEquals(result, 0);
}
```

When I run my test cases as usual using:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod
```

it is able to successfully run. I wonder how it is really working. I mean test classes and src classes are in different directories and are not part of the same jar. I need to know this because I am having a hard time to debug a problem and need better understanding of the working of both Maven and Spring.

Also another question in the above command does clean apply for both source and test Classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of accessing the classes is through JAVA CLASSPATH. Maven generates the folders that need to be added to system CLASSPATH and then injects them into the environment.

Once the folders where your class files are residing are added to CLASSPATH, Java takes care of finding the classes.

`mvn clean` applies to all the folders that are generated by Maven during build. You can find more information here.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html